# How to authorize users across the react-navigation app?

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation, expo

I have 2 groups of screens in my app.

> 1) AuthorizedScreens
>
> 2) NotAuthorizedScreens

As soon as the app loads I want to check if the user is logged in or not? If the user is logged in, the app loads **AuthorizedScreens** and if not, It loads **NotAuthorizedScreens**. How do i achieve this? I have included a sample of *not working code* but I guess that's how it could be!

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import store from './store';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  async componentWillMount() {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('facebook_token');
  }

  render() {

    const AuthorizedScreens = DrawerNavigator(...

    const NotAuthorizedScreens = DrawerNavigator(...


    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        { (this.token) ? <AuthorizedScreens /> : <NotAuthorizedScreens /> }
      </Provider>

    );
  }
}
```

**Note!**
I have an **action creator** that checks if the user is logged in. But I couldn't connect it to the **App** component, therefore I decided to use **AsyncStorage** to store a facebook_token, and if the token exist means user is logged in and if not the user is not...

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^20.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-20.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by *setting a state* in **componentWillMount** and calling it from **return**.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import store from './store';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    login_token: '',
  };

  async componentWillMount() {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('facebook_token');
    this.setState({ login_token: token });
  }

  render() {

    const AuthorizedScreens = DrawerNavigator(...

    const NotAuthorizedScreens = DrawerNavigator(...


    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        { (this.state.login_token) ? <AuthorizedScreens /> : <NotAuthorizedScreens /> }
      </Provider>

    );
  }
}
```

I have solved this problem, but I am not sure if I did it the right way! Because, **Redux** is in charge of my state management, but I manually used the react state management by setting state.

I will appreciate your inputs if you know a **better** way.